# Material UI: Use theme in React Class Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am looking for something like ThemeConsumer (which probably doesn't exist). I've React component and I am using `withStyles()` higher-order component to inject custom styles. It's pretty well described in [documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#1-specific-variation-for-a-one-time-situation) but I didn't find any example which uses theme.

---

I have some base component which contains **ThemeProvider**. It means any of MUI components are being affected by it.

```js
const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
const theme = getTheme(prefersDarkMode);
return (
   <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      ...
   </ThemeProvider>
)
```

I also use some functional components with `makeStyles()` to create styles with provided theme.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
   // here I can use theme provided by ThemeProvider
});
```

But **it can't be used in class components**. So I am using `withStyles()` HOC.

```js
const styles = {
   // I would like to use here provided theme too
}
export default withStyles(styles)(SomeComponent);
```

---

**Summary of my question:**
How do I use **provided theme** in class component?

Comment: I came here after googling "ThemeConsumer" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`withStyles` supports similar syntax as `makeStyles`:

```
const styles = theme => ({
   // here I can use theme provided by ThemeProvider
});
export default withStyles(styles)(SomeComponent);
```

Here's a simple working example:

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const StyledPaper = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
  }
}))(Paper);
export default function App() {
  return (
    <StyledPaper className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </StyledPaper>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit withStyles using theme]

Answer (score 5):

A component decorated with `withStyles(styles)` gets a special `classes` prop injected, which may be used for your custom styles. For example:

```
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core"
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"

const styles = theme => ({
  myCustomClass: {
    color: theme.palette.tertiary.dark
  }
})

class myComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props
    // In last line, you see we have passed `{ withTheme: true }` option
    // to have access to the theme variable inside the class body. See it
    // in action in next line.

    return <Box className={classes.myCustomClass} padding={theme.spacing(4)} />
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(myComponent)
```

If you pass `{ withTheme: true }` option to `withStyles` HOC, you'll get the theme variable injected as a prop also.

If you have other HOCs (e.g. Redux's connect, Router, etc) applied to your component, you may use it like this:

```
export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(
   withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(myComponent))
)
```

A more comprehensive explanation for this topic could be found in this article: [Using Material UI theme variable in React Function and Class Components](https://medium.com/swlh/using-material-ui-theme-variable-in-react-function-and-class-components-56f4b8164a00).

Answer (score 2):

Use `withTheme` HOC

modified example from [docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/)

```
import { withTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

class DeepChildRaw 
{
 /*...*/
  render()
  {
    return <span>{`spacing ${this.props.theme.spacing}`}</span>;
  }
}

const DeepChild = withTheme(DeepChildRaw);
```

Answer (score -1):

if are working with Class Components, you can use like here ;)

```
import React from 'react';
import Routes from './Routes';
import '../custom.css';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#fff'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#351436'
    }
  }
});

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Maybe provide some explanation to the code?