# I wanna to add a little gap on two TextField in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is my js file, I wanna add a little gap between them like padding. Many people are using box property to declare margin and padding but I don't know why I can't use the box property perfectly. If I use box property like ml={1} then the TextField is upside down. Don't forget the most important part is I wanna use this on a class component, not on a functional component.

```
<Grid item
      xs={12}
      sm={6}
      md={6}
      lg={6}
      xl={6}>
           <TextField label="Name"
                      variant="outlined"
                      color="primary"
                      size="small"
                      autoFocus />

           <TextField label="Address"
                      variant="outlined"
                      color="primary"
                      size="small"
                      multiline
                      rowsMax={1} />            
 </Grid>
```

Comment: I have posted the answer. Please review.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material UI: Use theme in React Class Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658547/material-ui-use-theme-in-react-class-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to solve is using makeStyles. I have given the complete code. Please review. I have referred to [Material UI: Use theme in React Class Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658547/material-ui-use-theme-in-react-class-component) sample for Class Component.

[image]

**Complete Code using Function Component:**

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  control: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

const App = () => {

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello MERN !!</h1>

      <br />

      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={6} xl={6}>
        <TextField label="Name"
          className={classes.control}
          variant="outlined"
          color="primary"
          size="small"
          autoFocus />

        <TextField label="Address"
          variant="outlined"
          className={classes.control}
          color="primary"
          size="small"
          multiline
          rowsMax={1} />
      </Grid>
    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Complete Code using Class Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
    }
});

class Car extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;

        return (
            <>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={6} xl={6}>
                    <TextField label="Name"
                        variant="outlined"
                        className={classes.root}
                        spacing={3}
                        color="primary"
                        size="small"
                        autoFocus />

                    <TextField label="Address"
                        variant="outlined"
                        className={classes.root}
                        spacing={3}
                        color="primary"
                        size="small"
                        multiline
                        rowsMax={1} />
                </Grid>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Car);
```

Comment: I wanna use this on a class component

Comment: Ok, give me few minutes. Let me give that a shot.

Comment: @RafiBhuiyan Attached is the code with Class Component. Please review

Comment: it's worked, thanks for this and I would like to know why you use React.Component instead of using Component.

Comment: Method 1:
```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Car extends Component {
}
```

Method 2:
```
import React from 'react';
class Car extends React.Component {
}
```

Comment: Sorry sorry that was my mistake to understand your code, I didn't notice the first few lines of your code
Btw thanks, My problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Grid item property in a Grid container.You have to wrap the Grid item property in a Grid Container Property.